# Can't make box scroll horizontally instead of vertically

Tags: html, css, horizontal-scrolling, vertical-scrolling

I'm having trouble with this problem of mine...
I'm making a website where the user can scroll left to right to see more details, but only in a specific box. Instead of scrolling horizontally, it scrolls vertically. I'm using `overflow-x:scroll`, but it still won't work. All the boxes inside `float:left` but still. I can't get it to work, and this website needs to be done soon!! Here is my code:

```css
.announce {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  width: calc(100% - 20px);
  padding: 10px;
  height:120px;
  overflow-x:scroll;
}

.section {
  float: left;
  margin:10px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);
}
```

```html
<div class="announce">
  <div class="section"> </div>
  <div class="section"> </div>
  <div class="section"> </div>
  <div class="section"> </div>
  <div class="section"> </div>
  <div class="section"> </div>
  <div class="section"> </div>
  <div class="section"> </div>
  <div class="section"> </div>
  <div class="section"> </div>
  <div class="section"> </div>
  <div class="section"> </div>
  <div class="section"> </div>
  <div class="section"> </div>
  <div class="section"> </div>
  <div class="section"> </div>
  <div class="section"> </div>
  <div class="section"> </div>
</div>
```

Anything is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Just fix the sizing of the divs to suit what you need, and then it'll be good to go...

```css
.announce {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  width: calc(100% - 20px);
  padding: 10px;
  height: 120px;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.section {
  margin: 10px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);
  display: inline-block;
  *display: inline;/* For IE7*/
  *zoom: 1;/* For IE7*/
  white-space: normal;
}
```

```html
<div class="announce">
  <div class="section"> </div>
  <div class="section"> </div>
  <div class="section"> </div>
  <div class="section"> </div>
  <div class="section"> </div>
  <div class="section"> </div>
  <div class="section"> </div>
  <div class="section"> </div>
  <div class="section"> </div>
  <div class="section"> </div>
  <div class="section"> </div>
  <div class="section"> </div>
  <div class="section"> </div>
  <div class="section"> </div>
  <div class="section"> </div>
  <div class="section"> </div>
  <div class="section"> </div>
  <div class="section"> </div>
</div>
```